# How do I go into a directory named "ls"?

Tags: unix, terminal

cd: ls, seems does not work, terminal gives a message "-bash: cd: ls: Not a directory".

Plz help, thx!

Comment: What operating system are you running? On linux or unix you simply run `cd /path/to/ls`.

Comment: I am using Mac OS.

Comment: So you need to run `cd ls` or `cd /path/to/ls` if `ls` is not in the current folder in which you are running `cd` (which can be found by running `pwd`).

Comment: [qwu246@compute bin]$ cd ls
-bash: cd: ls: Not a directory
[qwu246@compute bin]$ 

That is the message I got from my terminal...

Comment: Try drag and dropping the `ls` folder into the terminal... What path do you see?

Comment: Btw, no colons...

Comment: Sadly I am connected to a remote server, so the file is not actually on my computer. And I did not type the colon though, I dont know the terminal is giving one on the message...

Comment: What operating is the remote running?

Comment: What is the path to that ls folder?

Comment: It should be linux, but I am not sure which version it is.

Comment: The path is /usr/bin/ls

Comment: What is the output of `file /usr/bin/ls`? Do you see `/usr/bin/ls: directory`? If not, you are probably trying to `cd` to a file.

Comment: You can't cd to a file.

Comment: yes, what does `ls -ld ls` show? But, not really a programming Q, StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q seems  more appropriate for https://superuser.com, but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack OVerflow! Lot's of good information on this site.
Answer:
"ls" is NOT a directory (in your example), so you cannot CD to it.

Troubleshooting steps:

> -bash: cd: ls: Not a directory

Compare this result to the following:
`$ cd Hello
  -bash: cd: Hello: No such file or directory`

This means that, in my current directory, there is NO entry name *Hello*.
In your example, there IS an entry named *ls*, but it is not a directory.

Run the command:
`ls -la`
or
`/usr/bin/ls -la`
If you had a directory named *ls*, you would see an entry that looked something like this:
`drwx  ..... ls` The d indicates a directory.
You can also run the *file* command:
`file ls`
This will tell you what *ls* is (data, text, binary, etc.)
Here is the MacOS manual for the ls command: [ls command](https://ss64.com/osx/ls.html)
Here is the MacOS manual for the file command: [file command](https://ss64.com/osx/file.html)